# Taking control over urlbar in Firefox

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I would like to modify the urlbar to include additional functionalities. Something like [instantfox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/instantfox/) does.

For this I need 2 things:

1. I need to listen to keypress events from my extension.
2. I want to disable the default suggestions popup.

What would be the cleanest way to accomplish this?
If possible using the addon sdk.

Comment: If you already have an addon doing this, why don't you look at the addons code? Just download the addon's xpi file and dezip it.

Comment: I looked at it but the solution seems a bit messy. I was wondering if there is a better way to do it, maybe using the SDK. And instant fox does not remove the suggestions popup. I don't want to do a lot of overriding internal firefox code. I'm more looking for best practices in this case.

Comment: I take control of the urlbar in my addons ntHotkey it might be simpler for you to read. Basically you add keyup or keydown listeners.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have an add-on wip called [Fantastic Bar](https://github.com/erikvold/fantastic-bar) which does what you want.

Comment: Tnx. This is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably the messy way you mention in your comment, but I think it's the best way to do it with the SDK

```
const doc = require('sdk/window/utils').getMostRecentBrowserWindow().document;
var urlBarIcons = doc.getElementById('urlbar-icons')
var btn = doc.createElement('toolbarbutton');
btn.setAttribute('id', 'foo');
btn.setAttribute('image', loc('bar.png'));
btn.addEventListener('command', function(event) {
  urlBtnClick();
}, false);
urlBarIcons.appendChild(btn);
```

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at the [examples from addon-sdk wiki](https://github.com/mozilla/addon-sdk/wiki/Community-developed-modules#browser-ui), in particular the [awesomebar](https://github.com/autonome/Jetpack-Modules/blob/master/awesomebar.js) module, [how to](https://gist.github.com/autonome/669262) [use it](http://autonome.wordpress.com/2011/06/08/extensibly-awesome/). That's the easiest way to give custom suggestions on the urlbar.

I know it does not disables it (item 2 from your question) but you'll have control on what to suggest and maybe that way you don't need to  to listen to keypress events (item 1 from your question).